# How to compare shapes of ndarrays in a concise way?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-ndarray

I'm new to Rust.

Suppose a matrix `a` has shape `(n1, n2)`, `b` has `(m1, m2)`, and `c` has `(k1, k2)`. I would like to check that `a` and `b` can be multiplied (as matrices) and the shape of `a * b` is equal to `c`. In other words, `(n2 == m1) && (n1 == k1) && (m2 == k2)`.

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;

// a : Array2<i64>
// b : Array2<i64>
// c : Array2<i64>
```

[`.shape` method](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.shape) returns the shape of the array as a slice.
What is the concise way to do it?

Is the returned array from `.shape()` guaranteed to have length 2, or should I check it? If it guaranteed, is there a way to skip the `None` checking?

```rust
let n1 = a.shape().get(0);  // this is Optional<i64>
```

Comment: `ArrayBase::shape` returns a slice of length 2 iff the array is two-dimensional. If that's your case then yes, it's guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Array2 specifically there are [.ncols() and .nrows() methods](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.nrows). If you are only working with 2d arrays then this is probably the best choice. They return usize, so no `None` checking is required.

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn is_valid_matmul(a: &Array2<i64>, b: &Array2<i64>, c: &Array2<i64>) -> bool {
    //nrows() and ncols() are only valid for Array2, 
    //[arr.nrows(), arr.ncols()] = [arr.shape()[0], arr.shape()[1]]
    return a.ncols() == b.nrows() && b.ncols() == c.ncols() && a.nrows() == c.nrows();
}
fn main() {
    let a = Array2::<i64>::zeros((3, 5));
    let b = Array2::<i64>::zeros((5, 6));
    let c_valid = Array2::<i64>::zeros((3, 6));
    let c_invalid = Array2::<i64>::zeros((8, 6));

    println!("is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_valid) = {}", is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_valid));
    println!("is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_invalid) = {}", is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_invalid));
}
/*
output:
is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_valid) = true
is_valid_matmul(&a, &b, &c_invalid) = false
*/
```